# How to validate equivalency between two jpeg files

Tags: image, binary, jpeg

I have two jpeg files with different md5sums. I have produced these files using the same steps, and they should be equivalent. It seems as if each jpeg file produces a unique hash despite their equivalency. When I try using `diff`, all I get in return is:

```
Binary files first.jpeg and second.jpeg differ
```

Essentially, I need some direction in how I can reliably verify if two jpeg files are equivalent?

Comment: ImageMagick has a `compare` utility that creates an image that is the difference of two images - you could use that and check for pixels in the resulting image that are non-zero...

Comment: If your JPEG files contain EXIF information, then they probably include the EXIF date/time tag. This will cause a checksum difference between 2 identical images. If this is the case and you don't need that info, create your images without it.

Comment: @BitBank how can I view EXIF information?

Comment: There are plenty of free tools to examine EXIF info. Post a sample image and I'll tell you what I find.